# how to modify a BeautifulSoup object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Let's presume I have the following piece of code

```
text = '<link href="link">'

souped = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

tags = souped.find_all()

link_modified_tags = ResultSet()

for tag in tags:
   if tag.has_attr('href')
      link_modified_tag = tag
      link_modified_tag['href'] = 'modified_link'
      link_modified_tags.append(tag_copy)
      
   else:
      link_modified_tags.append(tag)
      
link_modified_souped = souped
```

How would I put the modified ResultSet back into `link_modified_souped` for further to-text transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *put back* modified tags, you modify tags *in-place*:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '<link href="link">'
souped = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

tags = souped.find_all()

for tag in tags:
    if tag.has_attr("href"):
        tag["href"] = "modified_link"

print(souped)
```

Prints:

```html
<link href="modified_link"/>
```

Comment: I'd say that is far not intuitive, but it works, OMG, thanks!!!

Comment: @DimonAgon  please mark the answer as accepted so that people don't waste their time checking the question.